# Wire high if exactly one high in Verilog

Tags: verilog

If I've got an array of 9 wires, is there an easy way to make a new wire that is high if exactly one of the 9 is high?  I know I could do

```
wire[8:0] data;
wire exactlyOneActive;
assign exactlyOneActive = (data[0] & !data[1] & !data[2] ...) | 
                          (!data[0] & data[1] & !data[2] ...) |
                          (!data[0] & !data[1] & data[2] ...) |
                          ...etc
```

but, yuck, right?  Especially since the nine wires will probably be 25 at some point.  Any better way to do this, maybe using `generate`?  It has to be synthesizable too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
assign zeroOrOnehot     = ~|(data & (data-1));
assign atLeastOneBitSet = |data;
assign exactlyOneActive = zeroOrOnehot & atLeastOneBitSet;
```

Regards - Cliff Cummings - Verilog & SystemVerilog Guru

Answer (score 4):

This should be a pretty efficient design.

```
wire[8:0] data;
wire exactly_one_active;

//Total is log2_ceiling of data bits wide
// Remove binary weighting
wire  [3:0] total = data[8] + data[7] ... + data[0]; 

assign exactly_one_active = (total == 4'b1);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this should work. For loop will be synthesizable as long as it has a constant loop counter, as this does:

```
#define N 8

wire [N:0] data;

reg [N:0] uniqueActive;

always @(data) begin
   for (i=0 ; i < N; i = i+1 ) begin
      uniqueActive[i] = (data == 1<<i);
   end
end

assign exactlyOneActive = (uniqueActive != 0);
```

Comment: is the variable i an integer or a register?

Comment: `i` would be an integer, in this example. This is still synthesizable as the loop would be unrolled at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

All the other solutions require O(N^2) gates.  Note the following pattern

```
(a#b#c#d#e#f#g#h) & (a&b # c&d # e&f # g&h) & (a&b&c&d # e&f&g&h)
```

where you test the aggregate xor, the xor of each pair, the xor of each group of 4, the xor of each group of 8 (not shown), etc, gives you a correct answer in O(N log(N)) gates.  (You can verify logic on [truth table generator](http://turner.faculty.swau.edu/mathematics/materialslibrary/truth/)).  Not sure how to write this in a concise way in Verilog though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an O(N) gate solution

```
wire[8:0] wires;
wire isOneHot;
wire[8:-1] moreThanOne;
wire[8:-1] atLeastOne;

genvar i;
generate
    for (i=0; i<9; i=i+1) begin :b1
        assign atLeastOne[i] = atLeastOne[i-1] | wires[i];
        assign moreThanOne[i] = moreThanOne[i-1] | atLeastOne[i-1] & wires[i];
    end
    assign isOneHot = atLeastOne[8] & !moreThanOne[8];
endgenerate
```

Answer (score -2):

Think in terms of logic: what do you want?
Say you had two wires: and you wanted to know is one high or not ... it's not an and, it's not an or ... wait, it's an xor (exclusive or ... one or the other but not both).

so what you want is:
assign exactlyOneActive = data[0] ^ data[1]  ^ data[2] ^ ...

perhaps the following is legal: data ^ 1b'0 (xor all bits with one zero bit)

Comment: But 1 ^ 1 ^ 1 = 0 ^ 1 = 1.  I think all that tells me is that I've got an odd number of high bits.

Comment: Oops. You're right. What you want is a one bit adder (so you can tell if there is carry or not, ie were both bits 0 or 1).